# Print the JSON value from AWS S3 bucket in Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

What is the way to get the response body of the uploaded JSON file to the lambda function to print it?
I used the following code but it is specified for Content Type. Any suggestions for this please?

```
// console.log('Loading function');
        
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
    
    

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
        
        //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    
        // Get the object from the event and show its content type
        const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
        const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        
        const params = {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: key,
        };
        
        try {
            const { ContentType } = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
            console.log('CONTENT TYPE:', ContentType);
            console.log('Body: ', );
            
            console.log("response: " + "I want to print the response body here when a JSON file uploaded")
            
            return ContentType;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            const message = `Error getting object ${key} from bucket ${bucket}. Error : ` + err;
            console.log(message);
            throw new Error(message);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return value of `getObject` contains `Body` field.

```
const { ContentType, Body } = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
console.log('CONTENT TYPE:', ContentType);
console.log('Body: ', Body);
```

Comment: Thanks this is working with SDK Version 2 well. But when we use NodeJs V18+ it uses SDK 3 and getting the bucket name and key is a trouble with it.

Comment: const bucket = event.Records[0].s3Client.bucket.name;
const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3Client.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' ')); these methods are not support with SDK 3 I guess